# What's the purpose of "delete [] element" in the given c++ code for implementation of a 1D array?

Tags: c++, data-structures

The following code is for implementation of 1 D array in C++. In the function 
`Array1D<T>& operator=(const Array1D<T>& v);` there is the expression `delete [] element` In the book it says that it's used for freeing the old space but I don't fully understand it. Can someone explain in detail why we need this expression?

```
template<class T>
class Array1D
{
public:
Array1D(int Size=0);
Array1D(const Array1D<T>& v);
~Array1D(){delete [] element;}
T& operator[](int i)const;
int SizeFunction(){return Size;}
Array1D<T>& operator=(const Array1D<T>& v);
Array1D<T>& operator+()const;
Array1D<T>& operator+(const Array1D<T>& v);
Array1D<T>& operator-()const;
Array1D<T>& operator-(const Array1D<T>& v);
Array1D<T>& operator*(const Array1D<T>& v);
Array1D<T>& operator+=(const T& x);
private:
int Size;
T* element;
};


template<class T>
Array1D<T>& Array1D<T>::operator=(const Array1D<T>& v)
{
if(this!=&v)
{
    Size = v.Size;
    delete [] element; // What's the purpose of this expression?
    element = new T [Size];
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
    {
        element[i]=v.element[i];
    }
}
return *this;
}
```

Comment: deleting previously allocated element if any..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, C++ allows you a lot more control over memory but this means you also have to be a lot more careful with it.

In essence, every time you call 'new' you are allocating memory to hold whatever you just created a new one of, in this case an element of the array.

Once you are finished with that memory, you need to tell the machine you no longer need it and that memory is now 'free' to be used for something else. In this case there are two instances where the memory is returned to the computer, the first you highlighted where an array is being destroyed before a new one is created and the second is in the destructor which returns all the memory used for the array elements when the array itself is destroyed.

As a basic rule in all C++ programs, if you 'new' something then you should also 'delete' it once you have finished with it.